# Display the amount of profit and discount percentage + product discount date range on the product page and product archive

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

WooCommerce products have two normal prices and discounted prices.
How can the amount of discount be displayed as a percentage after or before the sale price or the price with a discount?
And the number of discount days should also be calculated, for example (offer valid between 20 Jun 2023 and 25 Jun 2023) is equivalent to 5 days of discount.

**As in the following example:**

```
Price: $1200
Sale Price is: $240 with 80% off and you save ($960) money!
offer valid between 20 Jun 2023 and 25 Jul 2023 just for (5 days)
```

I used the following codes and the problem I have is that I get an error (Notice: Undefined variable: discount in...) in the archive page (product archive) or the product list because it cannot calculate the value of the discount date, but I don't know how to fix this problem.

Additional question and separate from the above question: Is it possible to display only the following values on the product archive page:

```
old price $1200 off 80% new price $240
offer just 5 days
```

*Note: If the possibility (// Your additional text in a translatable string) is available for translating texts in the future, it would be better.*

```php
/**
 * @ Add a custom text before the price display in WooCommerce
**/ 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'sale_dates_after_price', 10, 3 );
function sale_dates_after_price ( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    global $product;

    if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) 
        return $price;

    $date_from = $product->get_date_on_sale_from();
    $date_to   = $product->get_date_on_sale_to();

    if( is_product() && ! ( empty($date_from) && empty($date_to) ) ) {
        $date_from = date( "j M y", strtotime($date_from) );
        $date_to   = date( "j M y", strtotime($date_to) );
        $price    .= ' <span class="sale-dates"><strong>offer valid between '.$date_from.' and '.$date_to.'</strong></span>';
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Based on or related:
[Add a custom text before the price display in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016425/add-a-custom-text-before-the-price-display-in-woocommerce/47016988#47016988)
[Replace on sale product price with saving amount and percentages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557301/replace-on-sale-product-price-with-saving-amount-and-percentages-in-woocommerce/52561501#52561501)